# Java Inserting in a 2Darray

Tags: java, python, arrays, sorting

what  I'm trying to do in Java is the python `listname.insert(index, value)` function with a 2d array. I want to take two values and insert them at the beginning of my array and instead of replacing the values already there I would like to just push them down. What is a way I can perform this in Java?
Example code snippet

```
static int[][] snake_parts = {{320, 240},{320,260},{320,280}};
snake_parts.add([0], {100,100});
```

i apologize for my lack of code but it is hard to show source for something i cant quite figure out to do.
example in python

```
nums = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
print nums
nums.insert(0, (0,0))
print nums

output:
(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)

(0,0),(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ArrayList will do that can you use an ArrayList?

Comment: Can you explain more im relatively new to java

Comment: Study [Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). Arrays in Java are very limited.

Comment: There are many classes you could use. e.g. ArrayList and LinkedList. Their methods are described in the api documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/  The different collections differ in their performance behaviour and in the methods they offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your python example converted

```
    ArrayList<int[]> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    nums.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
    nums.add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
    nums.add(new int[] { 5, 6 });

    for(int[] n : nums)
    {
        System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
    }

    nums.add(0, new int[] { 0, 0 });

    for(int[] n : nums)
    {
        System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
    }
```

More information available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Update: Fully working class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<int[]> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        nums.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        nums.add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
        nums.add(new int[] { 5, 6 });

        for(int[] n : nums)
        {
            System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
        }

        nums.add(0, new int[] { 0, 0 });

        for(int[] n : nums)
        {
            System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run this bit of code i get two ArrayList is a unknown character errors how can i fix that?

Comment: Try using Ctrl + Shift +  O? --- This is the keyboard shortcut to import the libraries required

Comment: this still does not fix my problem here is the exact error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<int[]> nums = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: public class Array {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<int[]> nums = new ArrayList<>();
         nums.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        nums.add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
        nums.add(new int[] { 5, 6 });
            for(int[] n : nums) {
                System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
    }
         nums.add(0, new int[] { 0, 0 });
         for(int[] n : nums) {
             System.out.println(n[0] + " : " + n[1]);
      }
    }
}

Comment: Your code works for me. The ctrl+shift+O was meant to import the ArrayList library. Check the code provided in my answer for the import and add it to the top of your class

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 ArrayList<Integer[]> snake_parts = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    snake_parts.add(new Integer[]{1,2});
    snake_parts.add(new Integer[]{3,4});
    snake_parts.add(new Integer[]{5,6});
    snake_parts.add(0,new Integer[]{0,0});
    int[][] array= new int[snake_parts.size()][];
    array = snake_parts.toArray(array);
```